# Unit of Work, LazyLoading Disabled, Generic Repository, IncludeMultiple<T>, Http 500 error

Tags: entity-framework, api, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

1. I have a Vehicle with an association to Model, Model has an association to Make.
2. Here is my Generic Repository as pertaining to associations as LazyLoadingEnabled = false in my project:

   ```
   public IQueryable<T> IncludeMultiple<T1>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] associations) where T1 : class
   {
       var source = (IQueryable<T>)DbContext.Set<T>();
       if (associations != null)
       {
           foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> path in associations)
               source = DbExtensions.Include<T, object>(source, path);
       }
       return source;
   }
   ```
3. In my api controller, I am using Unit of work pattern. Here is my GetAll method:

   ```
   public IEnumerable<Vehicle> GetAll()
   {
     var vehicles = Uow.VehicleRepository.IncludeMultiple<Vehicle>(c => c.VehicleModel).ToList();
     return vehicles;
   }
   ```

Everything works fine and Json retrieves the Vehicle class data as well as the related VehicleModel class data.

However, Vehicle has no direct association to VehicleMake, only VehicleModel does. Now, if my GetAll method has this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Vehicle> GetAll()
    {
      var vehicles = Uow.VehicleRepository.IncludeMultiple<Vehicle>(c => c.VehicleModel, c => c.VehicleModel.VehicleMake).ToList();
      return vehicles;
    }
```

while I see in debug that vehicles does indeed have the vehicles and their relevant VehicleModel and VehicleMake data, it returns a Http 500 error in Fiddler.

---

Update:

---

Added another association in Vehicle called "Test", with the GetAll method being:

(c => c.VehicleModel, c => c.Test)

No error, all data was returned via fiddler. So, it appears that a "Non-direct association" (ie Vehicle -> VehicleMake) is the cause of the error.

---

Question:

---

What would be the correct way to retrieving the relevant Vehicle data and its associated classes' data and return it to Json while not getting a Http 500 error?

Comment: Can't you debug this to find the precise exception that is thrown? "*Http 500 error in Fiddler*" isn't the best error description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

**SOLVED **

---

This works:

```
  public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
  {
      var vehicles = from data in  Uow.VehicleRepository.IncludeMultiple<Vehicle>(c => c.VehicleModel,c => c.VehicleModel.VehicleMake)
                         select new 
                             {
                                VehDesc = data.Description,
                                VehVIN = data.VIN,
                                VehTransmissionType = data.TransmissionType,
                                VehFuelType = data.FuelType,
                                VehYear = data.Year,
                                VehMileage = data.Mileage,
                                VehCylinderSize = data.CylinderSize,
                                VehEngineSize = data.EngineSize,
                                VehVehicleModel = data.VehicleModel.Name,
                                VehMakeName = data.VehicleModel.VehicleMake.Name
                             };
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, vehicles);
  }
```

Basically,

```
 1. I used an HttpResponseMessage as my return type;

 2. I used projection to create an anonymous type;
```

Why did I have to do this?

As near as I can tell, the issue centered on JSON receiving a "circular" return with VehicleModel and VehicleMake. That is, VehicleModel had a association to VehicleMake and VehicleMake has a collection of VehicleModels. When I looked in my debug code I could see a cascade of VehicleModel to VehicleMake to VehicleModel, etc, etc, etc, so to me that meant it was circular.

If anyone knows a better way w/o using anonymous type nor removing the virtual keyword from my navigation properties, I would certainly like to know it. But this does truly work.

FinalNote: Be sure NOT to use the model's property names in anonymous type, ie replace property "TransmissionType" with something like "VehTransmissionType".

Comment: In my opinion that's not only a workaround but actually the better approach to load projected objects (either anonymous or named) instead of full entities for serialization. You should accept your answer :) BTW: You can remove the `.IncludeMultiple` from your code above because `Include` is ignored by EF anyway when you project. BTW2: You don't need to remove the `virtual` keyword to disable lazy loading and proxy creation. You can use: `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false` (or `...LazyLoadingEnabled = false`).